# OTA version 12.21 and ALM version 11.52 compatibility issue

Tags: excel, vba, alm

I am currently using both ALM 11.52 and ALM 12.21. There is an excel vba macro that I need to run on both the ALM versions 9as some projects are on 11.52 and some are on 12.21). But I get an error message that OTA version (12.21) is not compatible with ALM server version 11.52 when I try to connect to project which is on ALM 11.52. Is there a way I can solve the OTA compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, we can say that VBA uses OTA registed on system wide level. For this case only one client could be registered.
Frankly speaking you shouldn't try to work with 2 different client in same process. But if you need this you need load Side-By-Side manifest provided by ALM.
By default ALM clients located in folder
%LOCALAPPDATA%\HP\ALM-Client. In file Deployments.ini you can find where is exact ALM clients are deployed (in dependecy of ALM URL or version)
You can use file application.sxs.manifest to activate activation context that you need. Here is the sample code :

```vb
Private Declare Function CreateActCtx Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateActCtxA" (ByRef pActCtx As ACTCTX_) As Long
Private Declare Sub ReleaseActCtx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hActCtx As Long)

Private Declare Function ActivateActCtx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hActCtx As Long, ByRef lpCookie As Long) As Integer
Private Declare Function DeactivateActCtx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal ulCookie As Long) As Boolean


Private Declare Function GetLastError Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Declare Sub SetLastError Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwErrCode As Long)

Private Type ACTCTX_
    cbSize As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    lpSource As String
    wProcessorArchitecture As Integer
    wLangId As Integer
    lpAssemblyDirectory As String
    lpResourceName As String
    lpApplicationName As String
    hModule As Long
End Type

Private actctx As ACTCTX_
Private hActCtx As Long
Private actCtxCookie As Long

Const ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID As Long = 4
Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE As Long = -1

Const CREATE_CONTEXT_ERROR As Long = 1
Const ACTIVATE_CONTEXT_ERROR As Long = 2

Public Sub ActivateOtaContext(ByVal almClientDeploymendPath As String)
  Dim actctx As ACTCTX_, ativated As Integer


  If Right(almClientDeploymendPath, 1) = "\" Then
    almClientDeploymendPath = Left(almClientDeploymendPath, Len(almClientDeploymendPath) - 1)
  End If
  actctx.cbSize = Len(actctx)
  actctx.dwFlags = ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID
  actctx.lpAssemblyDirectory = almClientDeploymendPath
  actctx.lpSource = almClientDeploymendPath & "\application.sxs.manifest"

  hActCtx = CreateActCtx(actctx)
  If hActCtx = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + CREATE_CONTEXT_ERROR, , "Cannot create activation context. Error code: " + GetLastError
  End If
  If ActivateActCtx(hActCtx, actCtxCookie) <> 1 Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + ACTIVATE_CONTEXT_ERROR, , "Cannot activate context. Error code: " + GetLastError
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub DeactivateOtaContext()
  If actCtxCookie > 0 Then
    Call DeactivateActCtx(0, actCtxCookie)
    actCtxCookie = 0
  End If
  If hActCtx > 0 Then
    Call ReleaseActCtx(hActCtx)
  End If
End Sub

Sub Test()
  Dim tdConnection As ITDConnection10
  Dim AlmClientsBasePath As String
  AlmClientsBasePath = Environ("LocalAppData") + "\HP\ALM-Client"

  ActivateOtaContext AlmClientsBasePath + "\alm1221"

  Set tdConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
  tdConnection.InitConnectionEx "http://alm1221.company.net/qcbin/"
  tdConnection.LoginEx "user1", "pwd1"
  tdConnection.Logout
  tdConnection.ReleaseConnection
  Set tdConnection = Nothing

  DeactivateOtaContext

  ActivateOtaContext AlmClientsBasePath + "\alm115"


  Set tdConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
  tdConnection.InitConnectionEx "http://alm.company.net/qcbin/"
  tdConnection.LoginEx "user2", "pwd2"
  tdConnection.Logout
  tdConnection.ReleaseConnection
  Set tdConnection = Nothing

  DeactivateOtaContext
End Sub
```